# Multiple Cross-correlation

Tags: time-series, cross-correlation

I'm trying to compare two sets of time series. I've successfully used cross-correlation to compare two series between them, but I'm not sure about the way to go for several series.

Let me be more specific:

- A(t) is the reference set and is composed of 36 time series (A1(t) to A36(t))
- B(t) is the second set and is composed of 36 time series as well (B1(t) to B36(t))

A1 is only comparable with B1, A2 with B2 etc. I'm trying to calculate the correlation between A and B for the best possible delay.

My best solution so far is to :

- calculate the cross-correlation for every possible delay and every time series, resulting in a new set of series C (C1(t) to C36(t))
- calculate some kind of multiple cross-correlation between all this C series, in order to find the delay d at which the correlation between the correlations is maximal.
- and finally calculating the average of C(d)

I'm not confident this is the most efficient approach (which matters, because I need to give near real-time feed-back on the similarity between the streaming series A and the previously recorded reference B). If anyone here had experience with signal analysis, it would be of great help ...